# Showing a list of plugins to filter

Tags: java, plugin

How can I refactor this function? I show a list of plugins in JSF, and I should filter them. I added function `filterPlugins` but I have some questions:

1. Should we simplify block with conditional expression?
2. I reassign global variable "plugins" to introduce my filter function (is it not bad practice?)

**`load()`**

```
@NotNull
@DataModel("plugins")
List<Plugin> plugins;

public void load() {
    plugins = pluginManager.getPlugins();

    plugins = filterPlugins(searchParam);

    SortingUtil.sort(plugins, SortingUtil.SortType.ID_ASC);
    if (plugins.size() > 0) {
        if (plugin != null && plugins.contains(plugin)) {
            selectPlugin(plugin);
        } else {
            selectPlugin(plugins.get(0));
        }
    } else {
        plugin = null;
    }
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
private List<Plugin> filterPlugins(final String searchParam ){
      return (List)Iterables.filter(plugins, new Predicate<Plugin>() {
        @Override
        public boolean apply(@Nullable Plugin plugin) {
            return  plugin.getName().contains(searchParam)
                    || plugin.getNetworkClasses().contains(searchParam)
                    || plugin.getClassName().contains(searchParam);
        }
    });
}


@Override
public void selectPlugin(Plugin p) {
    plugin = p;        
}
```

**`Plugin.java`**

```
public class Plugin {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8424575107726996696L;

    @NotNull
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    private String name;

    @NotNull
    private String networkClasses;

    + setters and getters
}
```

I want to pay your attention this code interacts with JSF page:

```html
<a:support event="onRowClick" action="#{configPlugins.selectPlugin(p)}" reRender="pluginList"/>
<a:commandLink action="#{configPlugins.removePlugin(true)}" reRender="pluginList"/>
```

Comment: Welcome to CodeReview.SE ! I think we are missing some context here : what is intended ? what is the surrounding code of this function ?

Comment: I would also be interested in the declaration of `plugin` (singular), and the `selectPlugin` method (the `plugin = null;` vs `selectPlugin` (no assignment to `plugin`) looks a bit suspicious to me).

Comment: Add more code, maybe we can use the other functions to reduce this function's workload.

Comment: I've edit my question

Comment: Where does searchParam come from? Why isn't it a parameter of load()?

Answer (score 7):

**Early Return**

You can return early to reduce the nesting of your if statements:

```
if (plugins.isEmpty()) {
    plugin = null;
    return;
}
```

Also note that I changed `plugins.size() > 0` to `!plugins.isEmpty()`, I think it's more readable.

**Plugins Field**

Code like this:

> ```
> plugins = pluginManager.getPlugins(); // assign field
>
> plugins = filterPlugins(searchParam); // method expects plugins field to be assigned, 
>                                       // but doesn't work on it but returns instead
> ```

Can be a bit confusing. I would change it to:

```
plugins = filterPlugins(pluginManager.getPlugins(), searchParam);
```

And then change `filterPlugins` to:

```
private List<Plugin> filterPlugins(final List<Plugin> plugins, final String searchParam )
```

**plugin field**

I would still like to see the declaration of `plugin` as well as the `selectPlugin` method. As mentioned in the comments, it looks a bit like it might be bad design.

Comment: Beaty answer! I've add more information to my question

Answer (score 3):

A few things that are jumping me here, though it might get a little harsh :(

> ```
> @NotNull
> @DataModel("plugins")
> List<Plugin> plugins;
> ```

This one is smelly, because you are having database level validation annotations within processing code. It seems that you are mixing responsibilities here. There shouldn't be any necessity to annotate a `List<Plugin>` in a processing class with `@NotNull`.

Additionally this allows for multiple plugins. This could also be undesired, you might want to use a `Set<Plugin>` instead. And according to the [Principle of Information Hiding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_hiding), this should probably be private!

It seems that the `@DataModel` won't work with a `Set`, though, so you may as well ignore that part ;)

> ```
> public void load() {
> ```

`load` is not really a good name. Why would you expose loading? This smells. Instead you should *probably* make this method private and call it in your constructor. But as you don't show much more code, this could as well just be me.

> ```
>     plugins = pluginManager.getPlugins();
> ```

Why is it a `Manager`? Manager-classes tend to become [god-objects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/God_object) quite fast. I'd try to avoid them wherever possible. Additionally `XYManager` is somewhat unclear. What exactly does this class do? "It manages stuff" is not a valid answer!

> ```
>     plugins = filterPlugins(searchParam);
> ```

This one looks quite nice actually. Just like you I am a little concerned you reassign a classwide variable.

> ```
>     SortingUtil.sort(plugins, SortingUtil.SortType.ID_ASC);
> ```

This one could be somewhat smelly. It could be easier, if you'd implement [`Comparable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) in your `Plugin` class to provide a so-called "natural ordering", which allows you to drop this to use inbuild methods instead:

```
    Collections.sort(plugins);
```

The following code has already been addressed by [tim quite throughly](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/67333/37660), so for now that's it.